# Is it possible for Python threads to cause their parent/main process to execute code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pyobjc

**Background:** I've written a simple [RUMPS](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps)/PyObjC app that at various points makes HTTP requests and pops system alert dialogs. Most of the HTTP requests are threaded to avoid blocking the main execution.

**Query:** In PyObjC you're not supposed to create alert dialogs in background threads (only the main process is safe to do this) so I was wondering if there was a sensible pattern I could use to allow child threads to communicate back to their parent to notify it that an alert dialog should be created.

As an example:

1. Main program has a `popAlert()` method defined, which call PyObjC functions to create alert dialog.
2. Main program launches a thread that executes an HTTP request and wants to pop an alert when done.
3. Child thread, when HTTP request completes, somehow calls back to the main process to trigger `popAlert()`.

At the moment I have the child thread creating the alert dialog which apparently isn't safe in PyObjC.

I'm fairly new to threading/multiprocessing and the inter-thread communication examples I've seen so far seem to mostly involve child threads receiving messages from a queue-like mechanism, with the parent optionally blocking until the queue is empty. I haven't yet seen anything that indicates if it's possible to have the parent respond to a message from a child thread in the way I describe.

If doing this requires re-architecting, that's fine too – I'm not wedded to any particular multiprocessing approach.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide more detail. Many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [pyobjc_performSelectorOnMainThread](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/threading-helpers.html). It might be what you need. Here's a contrived usage example:

```
  class MyClass (NSObject):

     def divideByZero_(self, arg):
          return arg/0

     def doit(self):
         try:
             result = self.performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_(
                  'divideByZero:', 55)
             print result

         except:
             print "Division failed"
```

You can find it being used in a more concretely in this [PyObjC example app](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/examples/Cocoa/AppKit/WebServicesTool/index.html). Check out WSTConnectionWindowControllerClass.py in particular.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that example app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a queue to transfer messages from children to parent. The problem here is, that you need a message loop in the main thread, that reads the message queue regularly to display the messages.

Comment: see also https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your answer – am I right in thinking this would be problematic because the main thread wouldn't be able to do any other work while in the message loop?

Comment: @BigglesZX most programs that are providing GUI elements are built around an event loop to begin with, because that's what most GUI frameworks require. The event loop object typically provide an `add_callback` method (or something similar) that allows child threads to schedule a method to run in the main thread.

Comment: @BigglesZX take a look at `pyobjc_performSelectorOnMainThread`. It might be what you need.

Comment: @BigglesZX Here's the documentation for that: https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/threading-helpers.html

Comment: @dano Had a crack at this but haven't had any success yet - the call to `pyobjc_performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_` can't find the target method I specify, possibly due to an inheritance issue. Are you particularly versed in pyojbc? I can post some sample code if so, but if not I'm happy to abandon this pursuit :)

Comment: @BigglesZX, I've never used pyobjc or Objective-C at all, sorry! Just did some googling and found that link.

Comment: @dano - No worries. What's the correct SO etiquette here? Do you want to add an answer pointing to the documentation and methods you mentioned? It only seems fair that you get the credit, despite my issue with that specific solution right now.